# h:panelGrid renders empty table cells

Tags: jsf, primefaces, panelgrid

I have the following `<h:panelGrid>`:

```
   <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="panelGrid" > 
        <!-- heading -->
        <f:facet name="header">
            User Details
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.ViewUserdetailsLabel_id}"/>
        <!-- adding in a small effect here that will fade a message when a user hovers over the id number or username -->
        <h:outputLink id="id1" value="#">  
            <h:outputText id="id" value="#{userdetailsController.selected.id}" title="#{bundle.ViewUserdetailsTitle_id}"/> 
        </h:outputLink>                            

        <p:tooltip for="id" value="This is your I.D. Number" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewUserdetailsLabel_username}"/>
        <h:outputLink id="username1" value="#">  
            <h:outputText id="username" value="#{userdetailsController.selected.username}" title="#{bundle.ViewUserdetailsTitle_username}"/>
        </h:outputLink>                            
        <p:tooltip for="username" value="Your registered username, this can be changed" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />

        <f:facet name="footer"></f:facet>  

    </h:panelGrid>
```

I expected it to show up as

```
User Details
Id:          500
Username:    zzzzzzzz
```

However, instead it show up with some empty cells:

```
User Details
             Id:
             500
             Username:
zzzzzzzz
```

The same problem perists when I use `<p:panelGrid>` instead of `<h:panelGrid>`. How is this caused and how can I sovle it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a panel grid each immediate child component counts as a single table cell.

Those `<!-- heading -->` and `<!-- adding ... -->` comment lines count each as a single child. Those thus also counts each as a single table cell.

To solve it, just tell Facelets to skip all comments during view build time by the following `web.xml` entry:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then there's the `<p:tooltip>` which also counts as a single table cell even though it does not represent any immediate content. You need to wrap the tooltip and its target component in a `<h:panelGroup>` so that it represents a single table cell (additionally, you could alternatively also just put the comment in there).

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.ViewUserdetailsLabel_id}"/>
<h:panelGroup>
    <!-- adding in a small effect here that will fade a message when a user hovers over the id number or username -->
    <h:outputLink id="id1" value="#">  
        <h:outputText id="id" value="#{userdetailsController.selected.id}" title="#{bundle.ViewUserdetailsTitle_id}"/> 
    </h:outputLink>                            
    <p:tooltip for="id" value="This is your I.D. Number" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
</h:panelGroup>

<h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewUserdetailsLabel_username}"/>
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputLink id="username1" value="#">  
        <h:outputText id="username" value="#{userdetailsController.selected.username}" title="#{bundle.ViewUserdetailsTitle_username}"/>
    </h:outputLink>                            
    <p:tooltip for="username" value="Your registered username, this can be changed" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks that has partially solved it, it looks like it is also counting the '  <p:tooltip ' as a table cell, is there any way to stop this too ?

Comment: Found the solution is to move these as it is not required to have them by the object, thanks a lot for you help :)

Comment: Overlooked those tooltips. Put them in `<h:panelGroup>`. I updated the answer. Note that you can do the same for comments.